# Making photo of apollo from earth

Tags: moon, photography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has man walked on the Moon?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon)

Is it possible to see the Apollo landing station, US flag, footprints, moon rovers from Earth or from space (from Earth orbit, e.g. with the Hubble Space Telescope or other satellite)?

http://www.google.com/moon/ - these photos are very limited and very bad quality.
They were made in the 70s by a moon orbiting station.

Moon has no atmosphere. There are very powerful telescopes.

Why are there no other photos? 
Can telescopes magnify enough?

Comment: We already addressed this as part of the larger moon-landing-denial question. In particular, please take a look at the following photograph: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M9AZ1.jpg

Comment: Can't  agree that it is dupe. I provided link from Google Moon project and I believe the quality is very bad. (same photos as yours) Also I wish to see it myself in telescope in much better quality. I believe it should be possible.

Comment: Max, we are not going to address your wish - we only allow questions that skeptical of a well-known claim. In this case the only claim I can see is that we haven't been on the Moon. Please read our [FAQ] and linked welcome post.

Comment: @Max In answer to your question, it is NOT possible to see any of the Apollo landers with an earth or earth orbit based telescope. http://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/hubble_moon.html shows what Hubble can do - it's nowhere near good enough.

Comment: There's a good write-up about the optical resolution here http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2008/08/12/moon-hoax-why-not-use-telescopes-to-look-at-the-landers/#.VqV9xR9uRhE
TLDR: Yes, telescopes can't magnify that much. On Earth orbit, you'd need a humongous 100-meter telescope to see the module as 1 pixel. Below Earth atmosphere, even that won't help, as atmospheric distortion will render your efforts useless..

Comment: If the question is not "Did we walk on the moon?" but the (unnotable) "Can I see the results in a telescope?" it might fit on http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter sent back a number of pictures of various Apollo landing sites. See https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/apollo/revisited/#.WKIcfX_t-XB for the images...

Comment: But I still wondering why we can't see that from earth if we can look so deep in space. I thought school telescope must be able to do that.

Comment: @Max: *Check sashkello's link.* To sum it up, divide size of object by distance (needs to be same unit!), multiply by 206265, and you get the angular size in arcseconds. The Apollo descent stage is roughly 0.002 arcseconds -- and Hubble's resolution is about 0.1 arcseconds, i.e. it could see things on the moon if they were 200m or more across. You see things in your school telescope because they are *massively larger* than the Apollo artifacts, *and* sending significant amounts of light in your direction (in front of a mostly-black background). The Apollo artifacts do neither.